# Como dar um select e jogar valores numa mesma coluna

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Exemplo:

```
select 'a' as 'letras', 'b' as 'letras'
```

Quero jogar a letra 'a' e a letra 'b' na coluna 'letras', porém com esse código ele retorna 2 colunas com o mesmo nome, porém quero jogar os valores na mesma coluna e não sei como fazer isso e nem como pesquisar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma alternativa, é o `UNION` :

```
select 'a' as letras

union

select 'b'
```

Comment: Obrigado! Esse UNION me ajudou demais nas gerações de relatórios com alguns milhares de linhas rs